# 301 redirect using rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I recently rebuilt an ecommerce site and I need to put some redirects in it to account for the old category adn search results from the old siteto the new format. I have it almost working but it is carrying the query string to the new page. Here is what I have

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^group_id=4$
RewriteRule ^searchResult.php$ http://website.com/category [L,R=301]

I have other rewrite rules in there that are working fine so I put this on the top so it would not interfere with anything. This does work but it carrys the query string to the page. Any ideas what I am doing wrong. I did go through a ton of posts on here, thats where I came up with what I have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty query string in the target will clear it.

```
RewriteRule ... ...? [...]
```